# What is >>>symbol in verilog?

Tags: verilog

May I know what is this symbol >>> in verilog. When should I use it? Thanks!

e.g

```
always @(posedge Clock) begin
  if (Clear) begin
    a < = c>>>8;
    b < = d>>>16;
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is an [arithmetic right shift operator](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~traylor/ece474/lecture_verilog/beamer/verilog_operators.pdf) (see page 19-20 of the link). It is the reverse case from Java (Java `>>` is arithmetic right shift, while `>>>` is logical right shift).

Arithmetic right shift is to handle case when the number right-shifted is positive/negative with this behavior:

> Shift right specified number of bits, fill with value of sign bit if
>   expression is signed, othewise fill with zero

To illustrate, if you have `signed` expression with value of, say like this:

```
1000 1100 
--------- >>> 2
1110 0011 //note the left most bits are 1
```

But for `unsigned`:

```
1000 1100 
--------- >>> 2
0010 0011
```

The left most will be filled with `0`.

Comment: Hi Ian, May I ask you when I shift 2 bits am I correct to say that I am dividing 4. Similarly, when I shift 8 bit am i dividing by 256? Thanks!

Comment: @user292965 hi, it is you again. ;) You are close.. It *appears* to be like that... because when the right shifted bit is translated to number it becomes half of the original. Assuming arithmatic shift though... There is a case where shifting is not equal to dividing, for example in the case for `logical right shift` of negative numbers.

Comment: I just tried it :). Do you know whether the final result after shifting round up or round down? From your example it look like it round up.

Comment: @user292965 integer numbers are not rounded up or down, only floating numbers do... "from your example... round up" which one?